# Subtracting 1 from a function pointer

Tags: c, linux, signals

I saw this line in the `signal.h` in `/usr/include/sys/` on my mac. Based on it's use as the return type of the function `signal`, I'd expect `SIG_ERR` to be a pointer  to a function that takes an integer input and returns void. But the macro expansion of `SIG_ERR` seems to subtract 1 from a function pointer type, which I found weird. How does C parse it?

```
#define SIG_ERR         ((void (*)(int))-1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
( (void(*)(int)) -1)
```

does not subtract 1 from a function pointer, what it does is *cast* the constant value -1 to a function pointer.

As a side note, adding or subtracting from a function pointer is not allowed in ISO C and can only be done [as a (somewhat peculiar) gcc extension](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/operating-systems-and-server-administration/linux/0596009585/gcc-extensions-to-the-c-language/void_and_function_pointer_arithmetic) which basically handles it as if it were a char pointer;

> In GCC, addition and subtraction operations are allowed on pointers of type void, and pointers to functions. Normally, ISO C does not allow arithmetic on such pointers because the size of a "void" is a silly concept, and is dependent on what the pointer is actually pointing to. To facilitate such arithmetic, GCC treats the size of the referential object as one byte.

Answer (score 1):

On [the manual page of `signal()`](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/cgi-bin/manpage?2+signal) it reads:

> The **signal()** function returns the previous value of the signal handler, or **SIG_ERR** on error.

So this `-1` 'function pointer' simply is an error indicator value.

Of course subtracting `-1` from a pointer does not make sense on most platforms because of alignment constraints; a pointer will usually be a multiple of 4 bytes.